# Open graph story posted successfully using graph API but not seen neither on the timeline nor in the Activity Log

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

I am posting an Open Graph story using the graph API but the post is not shown anywhere on my Facebook wall and there is nothing in my Activity Log either.

I configured the story in the App dashboard. The object has one custom property and it is a self hosted object with a public URL. I used the object debugger tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to make sure that all the metatags (including the one for the custom property) are there and no errors are shown.

Then I make this call to post the story:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/namespace:action?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&method=POST&result=MY_OBJECT_PUBLIC_URL

and I get the post ID in the response:
{
   "id": "SOME_ID"
}

I can even get all the information related to the post using the graph API with the Post ID returned.

**HOWEVER, I DON'T SEE THE POST ANYWHERE ON MY FACEBOOK WALL, NEWS FEED or ACTIVITY LOG.**

Any ideas of what might be happening?

Comment: Can you post what you get as a response from the Graph API when you fetch the data on the returned post ID?

Comment: {
   "id": "POST_ID",
   "from": {
      "name": "a",
      "id": "ID"
   },
   "start_time": "date",
   "end_time": "date",
   "publish_time": "date",
   "application": {
      "name": "a",
      "namespace": "asd",
      "id": "app_id"
   },
   "data": {
      "result": {
         "id": "ID",
         "url": "url",
         "type": "asd:b",
         "title": "abc"
      }
   },
   "type": "asd:zxc",
   "likes": {
      "count": 0,
      "can_like": true,
      "user_likes": false
   },
   "comments": {
      "count": 0,
      "can_comment": true,
      "comment_order": "chronological"
   }
}

Comment: @JayNCoke, above is the structure of the response I get, had to abbreviate the info of some fields due to the characters limit for the comment on stackoverflow.

Comment: I have a similar problem described on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337780/facebook-story-published-with-simple-facebooks-publish-method-does-not-appear

Answer (score 6):

I am having a related problem (I think). Let me first say that I use our own Action Types and Stories (i.e. https://graph.facebook.com/me/:).

What I noticed is that while the action does not appear on my wall, it shows up on my friends' News Feed (so even if I can't see it, they can "like" and "comment" on it), and also putting it's ID on the Open Graph Action Debugger tool, I can see the post's details.

BUT, what I also noticed is that it shows up in my activity log! (button on the right-bottom position of your cover image) Then, if you go to each activity entry, there is a small icon on the right with a pencil on it. Clicking on it, it shows that this means that the activity/action/post/whatever is "allowed" on your timeline. But, if you change that to Show to Timeline, it will actually be shown!

So, I think this is where you/we should look further (for example a setting/permission request to enable this by default -- not sure if anything like that exists though).

Comment: This was exactly my problem! +1

Answer (score 5):

First at all you need to get approval for every item of your open graph story. You can test your application without approval un-publishing it and adding some user as testers in the ***Role*** settings.

Now, to see your open graph activity in your timeline after publish you should configure the Additional Capabilities for you action type. So you need to check the ***Explicitly Shared*** option in the Capabilities section for you action. After that you need to include the parameter ***fb:explicitly_shared=true*** in the open graph call.

You can take a look to the Additional Capabilities here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-actions#capabilities

Explicit shared should be added in the post parameters.

Comment: Checked the 'Explicitly shared' option in capabilities section but forgot to set the 'fb:explicitly_shared' action type property to true. Setting it solved my problem.

Comment: where is that option ?is it developer site or not?

Answer (score 1):

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310892/ios-facebook-sdk-post-open-graph-and-show-on-timeline-without-clicking-activit?rq=1)

You may need to enable the 'explicity shared' setting for the open graph action in the Facebook Developer App Dashboard in the website.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add "fb:explicitly_shared" action parameter with value 'true' while posting it.

Also you need to toggle explicitly_shared in Actions' properties configuration page.

You need to be an administer of the app otherwise you will need to get the Stories approved by Facebook.
Hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

I could totally be wrong, but you may need to [submit your Open Graph action to Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process/) for approval. And you'll need to [set explicit sharing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/explicit-sharing/) if you want your action to show in places other than your own timeline and activity.

I say I could be wrong because you should at least be able to see your action within your activity log. It's difficult to say without looking more closely at your Open Graph Action and Object.

Comment: Couple of weeks ago I was testing using the same process and same settings (without having Facebook approval) and I was able to see the post within my activity log at least and timeline. Not sure why it is not showing anymore even when the post seems to have been successfully published using the graph API. I'll keep digging...

Comment: were you able to resolve your problem? I have the same problem. 

i suggest using this: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/272754542855954/?method=GET&path=

Comment: don't forget to switch the field at the top right from open graph to the name of your application (its a drop down box).

Comment: I think it was an issue with the Facebook platform. After couple of days trying, posts started appearing again on my timeline and wall. Nothing changed in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I could post the stories but could not see it on the timeline, issue was FBDisplayName in the app has to be same as the one configured in the FB developer console.

Answer (score -2):

make sure to add the Canvas URL under the "App on Facebook" section, I hope it works for you