# Facebook API - does it keep track of shares via link pasting?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If a link is shared by pasting the link on a facebook post instead of the share button, will it be counted as a share?

I tried pasting this link (https://kabayanabroad.antdomus.com/as-a-parent-will-you-bring-your-kids-to-ksa/) and posted in my facebook timeline.
Then I checked the url statistic using FQL, and still got the same share count. It didn't seem to increment.

**FQL:**

```
SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count,
total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM
link_stat WHERE url = 'https://kabayanabroad.antdomus.com/as-a-parent-will-you-bring-your-kids-to-ksa/'
```

**RESULT:**
[image]

**FB share** 
[image]

*****************************************************

**UPDATE:** 3/10/2015

- When I comment on the posted link inside facebook, it increments the `comment_count`
- When I 'like' the posted link inside facebook, it increments the `like_count`
- When I share the posted link inside facebook using the share dialog, it increments the `share_count`

Does this mean it has to go through the SHARE DIALOG? And does this mean that if a link is shared only by copy-pasting the link it will not count as a share_count?

Comment: try this link it a similar question on stackoverflow.
[using-graph-api-but-not......][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926716/open-graph-story-posted-succesfully-using-graph-api-but-not-seen-neither-on-the

Comment: hi @pakistanimoon I didnt find it useful as it is a completely different issue. The posts in my case appear on the timeline (see image above) but it is not being counted as a share in the graph

Comment: hello @clintgh, did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you paste the link on the Facebook post it is getting counted as a share, together with each like, comment and share of your post.

The reason why you don't see the share number increasing is probably that you have already liked this specific page before.

Comment: The thing is, I haven't liked or did anything to the page other than share it to my FB using the link..

Comment: I updated the question, please have a look. It is counting like, comment and share if I do it inside facebook.

Comment: In my case it keep on updating the share_count (and of course total_count) each time I paste the link on my timeline (curious that I can do it even multiple times, and even if I delete the post the number stays the same). The only exception is when I share a photo and add the link to the description. Maybe your problem is associated with your particular user settings, what about trying with other user?

Comment: hmm.. strange. Did you try to use the page on my question or you used a different page to test? I tried to do it with another user account with a different PC but still got the same result

Comment: Yes, I have tested it with the same page you have tried.