# Do I need to submit my app to post publicly - Facebook Api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using nodejs to make https requests to graph.facebook.com to make posts for my page. When I send my request the post can only be seen by page admins. When I click "Allow on page" in my activity log I get a notification saying the post is visible on my page. However, when I log into a different account I can't see the post.

Based on what I saw from this post:

[Open graph story posted successfully using graph API but not seen neither on the timeline nor in the Activity Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926716/open-graph-story-posted-successfully-using-graph-api-but-not-seen-neither-on-the)

I decided to add fb:explcitly_sharing=true to the url I was requesting.
I couldn't find the setting to enable explicit sharing in my app dashboard.

How do I make my open graph posts appear for the public? Do I need to submit my app for approval before my posts appear to the public?

Comment: Just take the app live

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick!